# Getting particular server config from Git in Chef Solo

Tags: git, configuration, chef-solo

I don't want to use Chef Server as for now, but rather want to leverage Chef Solo. I need to keep configs (attributes and files) of particular servers in a separate Git repo. This is needed to keep cookbooks in an open repo while hiding configs in a private repo.

Is there a built-in possibility in Chef to get attributes and files from Git repo? How do you usually fetch them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look into using Berfshelf and [the environment cookbook pattern](http://blog.vialstudios.com/the-environment-cookbook-pattern/). This design pattern puts all cookbooks in their own repos, public or private.

Specifically, for the configuration of particular servers, you can use a cookbook in a private repo with a recipe using `node.set` as mentioned in that blog post. Or set attributes in the `attributes/default.rb` with a statement like `default['foobar']['version'] = '1.2.3'`. The open repo cookbooks that are not private can be berksified and run from the private cookbooks with `include_recipe "{open-cookbook}::{open-recipe}"`.

I have used this design patter before in combination with [knife-solo](http://matschaffer.github.io/knife-solo/), especially since Berkshelf support was added in 0.4.x. Specifically, I use the command `knife solo cook someuser@localhost --sync-only`. This will prepare the kitchen for installation on a target machine (download all berksified cookbooks, create solo.rb, etc. etc.) but not actually run the code. Or invoke as `knife solo cook someuser@targetnode` to prepare, sync and run chef-solo on the target node.

Comment: Thanks! I've seen that Berkshelf is going away (at least it's not going to work with Vagrant), is there a way that will work for both Vagrant & usual Server?

Comment: Berkshelf is definitely not going away, it's just the vagrant-berkshelf plugin. I think your options are either to use [test-kitchen](http://kitchen.ci/) (the [named successor](https://sethvargo.com/the-future-of-vagrant-berkshelf/) to vagrant-berkshelf plugin) or take chef_solo out of your Vagrantfile and just use knife solo with something like `knife solo cook vagrant@localhost --ssh-port 2222` (i haven't tested this).